# Retrive MS SQL Server performance

Tags: sql-server, performance

I need to measure the performance of a MS SQL database, possibly with a query.
There is a way to obtain the average execution time of the more heavy query in a certain period of time?

Comment: use sp_whoisactive and log it to table so you can analyze the data http://whoisactive.com/docs/25_capturing/

Comment: some pointers here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/performance/troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-issues

Also check out Query Store

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, don't just look at duration; look at CPU, (logical) Reads, and Writes.  Spills if you can are also useful, and (physical) Reads just to see if your buffer isn't full/is too small.  Note that Duration is by far the most variable, followed closely by CPU in many modern systems.

Running a tightly targeted Profiler or Extended Events session with SQL:Completed or SQL:BatchCompleted and/or RPC:Completed events is your best option for accurate data over limited periods of time... but know you're putting more load on the server.  You can export the saved events

If the plan is ending up in the plan cache and staying there, then you can look at the system tables regarding plan cache statistics like sys.dm_exec_query_stats either with your own code, or with something like Brent Ozar's sp_BlitzCache:
https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/

Answer (score 0):

very useful script

[SQL Server 2017 Diagnostic Information Queries:](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/sql-server-diagnostic-information-queries-for-november-2017/) see comment (CPU)

Query 34, 39, 41, 42, 57

```
-- Get top total worker time queries for entire instance (Query 42) (Top Worker Time Queries)
    SELECT TOP(10) DB_NAME(t.[dbid]) AS [Database Name], 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(t.[text], 255), CHAR(10),''), CHAR(13),'') AS [Short Query Text],  
    qs.total_worker_time AS [Total Worker Time], qs.min_worker_time AS [Min Worker Time],
    qs.total_worker_time/qs.execution_count AS [Avg Worker Time], 
    qs.max_worker_time AS [Max Worker Time], 
    qs.min_elapsed_time AS [Min Elapsed Time], 
    qs.total_elapsed_time/qs.execution_count AS [Avg Elapsed Time], 
    qs.max_elapsed_time AS [Max Elapsed Time],
    qs.min_logical_reads AS [Min Logical Reads],
    qs.total_logical_reads/qs.execution_count AS [Avg Logical Reads],
    qs.max_logical_reads AS [Max Logical Reads], 
    qs.execution_count AS [Execution Count], qs.creation_time AS [Creation Time]
    ,t.[text] AS [Query Text], qp.query_plan AS [Query Plan] -- uncomment out these columns if not copying results to Excel
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs WITH (NOLOCK)
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) AS t 
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) AS qp 
    ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC OPTION (RECOMPILE);
    ------
    -- Helps you find the most expensive queries from a CPU perspective across the entire instance
    -- Can also help track down parameter sniffing issues



-- Top Cached SPs By Total Worker time. Worker time relates to CPU cost  (Query 57) (SP Worker Time)
SELECT TOP(10) p.name AS [SP Name], qs.total_worker_time AS [TotalWorkerTime], 
qs.total_worker_time/qs.execution_count AS [AvgWorkerTime], qs.execution_count, 
ISNULL(qs.execution_count/DATEDIFF(Minute, qs.cached_time, GETDATE()), 0) AS [Calls/Minute],
qs.total_elapsed_time, qs.total_elapsed_time/qs.execution_count 
AS [avg_elapsed_time], qs.cached_time
FROM sys.procedures AS p WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS qs WITH (NOLOCK)
ON p.[object_id] = qs.[object_id]
WHERE qs.database_id = DB_ID()
AND DATEDIFF(Minute, qs.cached_time, GETDATE()) > 0
ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC OPTION (RECOMPILE);
------
-- This helps you find the most expensive cached stored procedures from a CPU perspective
-- You should look at this if you see signs of CPU pressure
```

P.S.
[new versions](https://glennsqlperformance.com/2022/03/06/sql-server-diagnostic-information-queries-for-march-2022/)

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely look at query store if it's not already enabled.
I created a monitoring tool for SQL Server which can capture wait stats, cpu, io, stored proc execs, running query snapshots, slow query executions, perf metrics and more.
It's free and open source:

https://dbadash.com/